# Como fazer um controle de abas do navegar abertas pelo meu software com JavaScript e localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, front-end

Minha pergunta é como fazer um controle de abas, abertas do navegar pelo meu software, com JavaScript e localStorage? Por diversos motivos que não vem ao caso meu software web trabalha com a abertura de novas abas do navegador a cada funcionalidade que o usuário deseja acessar, com isso é necessário que eu controle principalmente a quantidade de abas abertas para que os seguintes requisitos sejam atendidos:

- Existe um controle de sessão que deve se manter ativo enquanto ao menos uma aba estiver aberta;
- Ao fechar todas as abas a sessão deve ser encerrada;
- Ao utilizar a opção "Sair do sistema" com várias abas abertas, deve fechar todas as demais abas e redirecionar a aba atual para a página de login, encerrando também a sessão;

Comment: Freddie Highmore, é você?

Comment: Não Sílvio, hehehe

Comment: Galera como eu poderia ser mais específico nesse tipo de pergunta?

Comment: Esse seu "software" que controlaria as abas seria feito em qual linguagem?

Comment: Esse controle deve envolver somente o front-end, neste caso, HTML5 e javascript (jquery).

Comment: Acho que não é possível fazer isso apenas com linguagens web..

Comment: @LucasBoeingScarduelli conseguiu realizar esse tipo de controle?, tenho um software web que precisa ter esse tipo de controle